# Unable to get to another screen from react-navigation deep linking

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, deep-linking

Given the following setup:

```js
const config = {
  screens: {
    Discover: 'discover',
    Theater: {
      screens: {
        Watch: 'watch/:name?',
      },
    },
  },
}

export const linking: LinkingOptions<any> = {
  prefixes: ['test://'],
  config,
}

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator()
export function TheaterStackScreen({route}: Props) {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
      <Tab.Screen name="Watch" component={WatchScreen} initialParams={{name: route.params.name}} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  )
}

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator()
export function StackScreen() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
      <Stack.Screen name="Discover" component={DiscoverScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Theater" component={TheaterStackScreen} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  )
}
```

...and running:

```
npx uri-scheme open "test://watch/test" --android
```

I recieve:

```
Android: Opening URI "test://watch/test" in emulator
```

...with no errors, however, there is no navigation within the app...
and this warning:

> WARN  The navigation state parsed from the URL contains routes not present in the root navigator. This usually means that the linking configuration doesn't match the navigation structure. See https://reactnavigation.org/docs/configuring-links for more details on how to specify a linking configuration.

Does something look inherently wrong with this setup?

current setup:

```json
"@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "6.3.1",
"@react-navigation/native": "6.0.10",
"@react-navigation/native-stack": "6.6.2",
"react-native": "0.68.2",
```

This is being run on device, but I don't get any different behavior on sim either.  I've attempted with debugger on and off with no difference.

### Edit with more details

```js
const {createNavigationContainer} = Bugsnag.getPlugin('reactNavigation') as BugsnagPluginReactNavigationResult
const BugsnagNavigationContainer = createNavigationContainer(NavigationContainer)

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator()

...

<BugsnagNavigationContainer linking {linking} onStateChange={(state: any) => {
  const newRouteNam = Analytics.getActiveRouteName(state)
  if (routeName !== newRouteName) {
    analyticsClient.screen(newRouteName)
    setRouteName(newRouteName)
  }
}}>
  <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
    <Stack.Screen name="Main" component={StackScreen} />
  </Stack.Navigator>
</BugsnagNavigationContainer>
```

### Edit 2

Unfortunately, updating the config had no effect, I still see the tracking but no navigation or opening of the specified path:

```js
const config = {
  screens: {
    Main: {
      screens: {
        Discover: 'discover',
        Theater: {
          screens: {
            Watch: 'watch/:name',
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
}
```

results:

> TRACK (Deep Link Opened) event saved {"event": "Deep Link Opened", "properties": {"referring_application": "android-app://com.android.shell", "url": "test://watch"}, "type": "track"}

Comment: Can you share  `<NavigationContainer  linking={ linking }>` implementation code

Comment: Its just as you posted, but with an added: 
`linking={linking} onStateChange={(state: any) => {...}`

Comment: I mean all content of  `<NavigationContainer  linking={ linking }> ....children  <NavigationContainer/>`

Comment: I added some more details, and in doing so I may have found the issue.  "Main" is not in the config as the root stack.  I'm going to plug that in and test.

Comment: New edit, no new results by updating the config...

Comment: Are you using Expo or React Native CLI?

Comment: .........RN CLI